# Copy lines between from opening and closing brackets in vim

Tags: vim, copy

I have a piece of code, and it has an opening and corresponding closing brackets. I need to copy the code within that braces and paste it some other place. I need to do this for a number of times, so I need keyboard commands so that I can enable recording.

For example:

```
abc{  //beginning of code
    somelines
     {
       some lines
     }
    abc
    {
      some lines
    }
}// end of code
```

I need to copy `abc {` to `}//end of the code`. The line number may change, inside also there will be sub-block. Using mouse if we double-click braces, it will select to end of the block. But I need avkeyboard command so as to use as a macro.

Comment: **First**; type `qaq` to erase the content of register  `a` then put cursor on `abc {` line and  create your macro by `qaV%yq`  after that for each block type `@a` to select the block and go to any line and paste it with `p`

Comment: Might be better suited for [vi.se].

Answer (score 3):

Yank( **y** ) inside( **i** ) brackets( **{** ) should do this for you: `yi{`

If you have round brackets: `yi(`

If you want to copy it to your GUI clipboard, just use the **+** registry: `"+yi{`

Answer (score 0):

You can copy this macro: `/{^Myi{npjdd` to registry `a`. To do this go to visual mode by typing `v`, then select the macro and copy it to registry `a` using: `"ay`. Then place the cursor before the first `{` of the document and type `2@a`. Here `2` can be replaced by the number of times you want the macro to be repeated. By using this macro in the following code:

```
{
  code1
}
{

}
{
  code2
}
{

}
```

I get:

```
{
  code1
}
{
  code1
}
{
  code2
}
{
  code2
}
```

Comment: But I have openings and closing braces inside the code1  itself. Nested codes.